# MySQL - UPDATE query not effecting row

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this update query not working even it doesn't show any errors, only no rows effected/ matched:

```
UPDATE `Budget` SET `amount` = 500, `rest` = 500 WHERE `company_number` = 1 AND `section_number` = 1 AND `chapter_number` = 1 AND `article_number` = 3 AND `subarticle_number` = 0 AND `ssubarticle_number` = 0
```

But when I do a "SELECT" from the database I got a row returned:

```
SELECT * FROM Budget WHERE `company_number` = 1 AND `section_number` = 1 AND `chapter_number` = 1 AND `article_number` = 3 AND `subarticle_number` = 0 AND `ssubarticle_number` = 0
```

This is "budget" table:

```
CREATE TABLE `budget` (
  `budget_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_number` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `section_number` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `chapter_number` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `article_number` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subarticle_number` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ssubarticle_number` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `rest` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `insert_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `transfer_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `has_children` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`budget_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The method I use to run the queries.

```
public bool UpdateTransfer(string companyNumber, string sectionNumber, string transferNumber, string TransferDate, 
                                   string[] budgetRow, string oldAmount, string newAmount)
        {
            MySqlTransaction tr = connection.BeginTransaction();
            cmdQuery = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmdQuery.Connection = connection;
            cmdQuery.Transaction = tr;
            try
            {
                cmdQuery.CommandText = @"SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;";
                cmdQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();


                // First, we return the old amount to the source row budget
                cmdQuery.CommandText = @"UPDATE Budget SET `rest` = `rest` + " + oldAmount +
                                        " WHERE `company_number` = " + companyNumber + " AND `section_number` = " + sectionNumber +
                                        " AND `chapter_number` = " + budgetRow[0] + " AND `article_number` = " + budgetRow[1] +
                                        " AND `subarticle_number` = " + budgetRow[2] + " AND `ssubarticle_number` = " + budgetRow[3];
                cmdQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(cmdQuery.CommandText);

                // Second, we make the transfer and substract the new amount from the source row budget
                cmdQuery.CommandText = @"UPDATE `Budget` SET `rest` = `rest` - " + newAmount +
                                        " WHERE `company_number` = " + companyNumber + " AND `section_number` = " + sectionNumber +
                                        " AND `chapter_number` = " + budgetRow[0] + " AND `article_number` = " + budgetRow[1] +
                                        " AND `subarticle_number` = " + budgetRow[2] + " AND `ssubarticle_number` = " + budgetRow[3];
                cmdQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(cmdQuery.CommandText);

                // Third, update the rest and new amount of destination row budget
                cmdQuery.CommandText = @"UPDATE `Budget` SET `amount` = " + newAmount + ", `rest` = " + newAmount +
                                        " WHERE `company_number` = " + companyNumber + " AND `section_number` = " + sectionNumber +
                                        " AND `chapter_number` = " + budgetRow[4] + " AND `article_number` = " + budgetRow[5] +
                                        " AND `subarticle_number` = " + budgetRow[6] + " AND `ssubarticle_number` = " + budgetRow[7];
                cmdQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(cmdQuery.CommandText);

                // Last step, update the transfer table.
                cmdQuery.CommandText = @"UPDATE `Transfer` SET `amount` = " + newAmount + ", `transfer_date` ='" + TransferDate + "'" +
                                        " WHERE `transfer_number` = " + transferNumber +
                                        " AND `company_number` = " + companyNumber + " AND `section_number` = " + sectionNumber +
                cmdQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(cmdQuery.CommandText);

                cmdQuery.CommandText = @"SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;";
                cmdQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
                tr.Commit();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error " + ex.ErrorCode.ToString());
                tr.Rollback();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the result of your SELECT statement?

Comment: It will only give you an updated rows count if something changed. Maybe they're already updated?

Comment: You've tagged this as a `C#` question. Does your `UPDATE` only not work through C#, or does it not work from the command line as well?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax @H Aßdøµ I ran it through SQL Fiddle and the query worked. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ad33/1 Please show some C# code.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII A row from the table returned.

Comment: @tadman Unfortunately no, this is what I get: `/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.047 sec. */`.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax i updated my question, please see it.

Comment: What's your connection string?

Comment: This code is crazy vulnerable to sql injection. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how you can verify if there are row changes after executing your sql on C#

```
public static Boolean PerformDatabaseAction(string sqlQuery) 
{
    using (SqlConnection con = DbConnect()) // Get SqlConnection
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery); 
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery); 
        CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text; 
        Connection = con; 
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Gets the count of affected rows
        if(rows > 0)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
}
```

And your query works so try it on this one.

Comment: I tried both, executing the queries from C#, and doing it manually, some queries work, and the other not. This why I couldn't understand.